# Setting height of html img element with function

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm trying to set the height of images loaded into my html file with Django as such:

```
<img data-original={{img.url}} width='310' height=calcHeight({{img.height}}, {{img.width}})/>
```

With the 'calcHeight(h,w)' function being a simple function to scale the height of the image in proportion to the width of 310. I have to do this because I use a lazyloader plugin that needs to generate empty placeholders for the images prior to loading the images themselves. The images are of varying dimensions so I need to get the height and the width of the images before the actual images are loaded, otherwise the placeholders will be of 'no height' prior to loading the actual images, causing the layout to get messed up in the process.

The code above doesn't work and I'm guessing it is because you can't call a function for height like that. I hope I explained the question precise enough and thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: what "doesn't" work? do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, the height is essentially set to 0, giving the placeholders no height upon loading the webpages. This causes the images to overflow into other  images/text when they do load once they are scrolled into the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a function that takes arguments inside a Template with Django. In order to achieve that you'll need to [write a template tag or filter yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags).

Then you'd be able to do something like:

```
{% my_img_tag img.url img.height img.width %}
```

Which would go in your tag constructor:

```
def my_img_tag(url, height, width):
    new_height = calcHeight(height, width)
    return {'url': url, 'height': new_height, 'width': width}
```

And you template could something like:

```
<img data-original="{{url}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"/>
```

Comment: Ah so you're essentially calculating the new height upon uploading the image in the database, instead of calculating it upon loading the webpage?

Comment: @dutchJSCOOP Do you wish to calculate an image that appears on the webpage and does not come from the server? Django template is rendered on the server so it is unaware of client context, if that's the case perhaps calculating it with javascript would achieve the desired effect.

Comment: No I wish to calculate the image height that comes from the django backed server.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by calculating the scaled height of the image once saved to the django database as such:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.photo_scaledHeight = self.photo_height * (310/self.photo_width)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I added the field 'photo_scaledHeight' to the model where photo was used so I could simply call that in my template like so:

```
<img data-original={{photo.url}} width='310' height='{{photo_scaledHeight}}' />
```

@lucas-lazaro pointed me in the right direction